# Joda Time - Cannot run JUnit tests in Eclipse or IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, junit, jodatime

I cloned the joda-time GitHub repository locally, imported it as a Maven project in both Eclipse and IntelliJ Idea and it built absolutelly fine in both IDEs. But when trying to run the JUnit tests it just will not work in either IDE and I cannot see what the issue is.

I know that I need to create an additional folder

```
src\tz-data\org\joda\time\tz\data
```

and place in there the two files

```
CET
ZoneInfoMap
```

and I have done all that.

The JUnit tests still do not run and the funny thing is that I get completelly different errors under Eclipse:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.getTest(JUnit3TestLoader.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit3TestLoader.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The datetime zone id 'Europe/Paris' is not recognised
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID(DateTimeZone.java:234)
    at org.joda.time.TestLocalDate_Basics.<clinit>(TestLocalDate_Basics.java:50)
    ... 10 more
```

and under IntelliJ Idea:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.joda.time.TestAbstractPartial
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:58)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:280)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:140)
    at com.intellij.junit3.TestRunnerUtil.createClassOrMethodSuite(TestRunnerUtil.java:147)
    at com.intellij.junit3.TestAllInPackage2.<init>(TestAllInPackage2.java:32)
    at com.intellij.junit3.TestRunnerUtil.getTestSuite(TestRunnerUtil.java:78)
    at com.intellij.junit3.JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.java:43)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Any tips on how to get around this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Looking in their pom.xml it relies on the exec plugin to call the org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoCompiler and generate some files.

In intellij I went into the maven bar and ran the compile step of the lifecycle and after that unit tests worken.

Comment: Thanks roby, you're right. I actually figured it out, eventually... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to maven and it turns out the issue was with the way I was trying to run the tests.

As noted by roby, I should have used the maven bar in IntelliJ to run the correct maven goal (simmilarly, I should have used Run As.. and the correct maven goal in Eclipse), whereas I was just trying to run the tests by using the IDE, i.e. right click on the project and 'Run All Tests' which understandably did not work as it was not using the correct configuration.